# Responsive width of elements inside of absolute div?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to add a responsive width to some boxes inside of an absolute container:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqkugona/)

Code snippet in regards to container and box elements:

```
.popbody{
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  max-width: 830px;
  max-height: 450px;
  width: 100%;
}

.popboxes{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 166px;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 90px;
  min-height: 75px;
  float: left;
}
```

Giving the container and boxes a 100% does not enable a responsive width when resizing the browser. When I try to wrap the box elements inside of a div with non-absolute positioning and 100% width, it breaks things.

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do or am I just using a bad approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after but changing your min and max width values to vw or a % it won't break the boxes.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wkm8v1bu/)

```
.popbody{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    max-width: 830px;
    max-height: 450px;
  width: 100%;
}

.popboxes{
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 20vw;
    min-width: 15vw;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 90px;
    min-height: 75px;
    float: left;
}

.boxinner{
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
   left: 0;
   right: 12px;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 8px;
}

.redbox{
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 50vw;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Viewport Sized Type](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Comment: Thank you! If no one else comes with a better answer, I'll put your feedback as correct answer tonight. Do you think I should battle with using those vw measurements or should I just use media queries to use fixed sizes for different devices? This is not for a formal website, it's rather a coding challenge

Comment: @ Doge personally I just started using viewport and find it to be very useful. I usually use a mix of viewport and %, haven't really done a lot with media queries so not the best to ask.